# Space Error when typing Korean

Tags: multibyte

when typing Korean, I quite frequently have a space error, and it seems happening randomly.

Suppose I am trying to write the sentence "I do not know" in Korean.
When I hit the space key after 'not' to write 'know', the location of space is supposed to be after 'not', but sometimes it is between 'o' and 't' like 'no t'.

I do not have this problem when typing in English and have no clue why.

[image]

on the third line, I wrote even the same word, and the error randomly took place.

here is a part of my .vimrc:

```
 set encoding=utf-8
 set fileencoding=utf-8
 set guifont=Menlo:h14
 set guifontwide=NanumGothicCoding:h14
 set formatoptions+=mB
```

Comment: Most likely the characters are double-width or similar and confuse vim. Some digraphs even do this.

Comment: If you type exactly the exact same text into a new buffer, does the error occur in the same place, or is it more random than that? From first appearances, this looks like an actual bug, in which case you might be better off asking on [the Vim issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues), although you should probably ensure that it's not caused by any of your plugins before doing so.

Comment: Thank you guys for your interest and suggestion. I will research more about double-width characters and whether it is an actual bug or not.

Comment: It is not an actual bug of Vim. it turns out due to my input method engine, ibus-hangul. Thank you guys.

Comment: 이 문제는 ibus 대신 fcitx를 사용하여 해결되었습니다.